# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,2) (4,2,100)

Tags: python, numpy, psychopy

Using the PsychoPy builder, I'm trying to create a stimuli that consists of 100 lines that are randomly positioned with orientations sampled from a gaussian distribution. I'm trying to set up the values for the position (pos) and orientations (ori) using the the builder's coding window; here is the script I use:

```
ori = []
pos = []

for i_ori in range(100):
    
    ori.append(random.gauss(mu, sigma))

x = np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, 100)

for i_pos in range(100):

    
    y = [np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1), x[i_pos]]
    pos.append(y)
```

I'm getting the error message:

```
File "C:\Users\r02mj20\AppData\Local\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\psychopy\tools\monitorunittools.py", line 69, in _height2pix
    return (pos + vertices) * win.size[1]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,2) (4,2,100)
```

I'm new to python (and coding in general), so I'm not sure where the values (100,2) (4,2,100) are coming from. I've tried editing the code (e.g., removing the orientations or removing the positions) to see if I could work it out, but it doesn't seem to matter what I do, I get the same error message each time. Any help would be greatly appreciated- thanks.

Comment: I could use more information, are you passing the __ori__ and __pos__ to a function in the PsychoPy library? you aren't editing the library files are you? - cause don't do that

Comment: For future reference, please post the _entire text_ of the error message, and all relevant code. The code you show above is not what gives rise to the error: all it does is create variables. The error presumably arises when you attempt to pass one of those variables to a PsychoPy stimulus whose API expects a parameter to be of a different shape (i.e. dimensions) than you are providing. Without seeing that offending call, it is very difficult to help you.